# Transfer table rows from one page to another page using HTML and Javascript

Tags: html

how to transfer table rows from one page to another page using HTML and Javascript

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $(document).on("click",".transrows",function(){
             var getselectedvalues  = $(".maintable input:checked").parents("tr").clone().appendTo($(".secondtable tbody").add(getselectedvalues));
        });
    });
</script>
```

second table is the class of another HTML page

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you want to edit the markup for another HTML page, found at another URL. Is that correct? If so, sorry to tell you, that's not how HTML works. There are ways to pass information between pages, but I think you might need to go back to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/DOM

Answer (score 0):

If you are using asp.net then you can use a Session. Otherwise, you can use a cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) api

Store the table row to localStorage:

```
localStorage.setItem('tableRow', `<tr>.... </tr>`)
```

Retrieve the data:

```
table.appendChild(localStorage.getItem('tableRow'));
```